# Dialog growing because of internal view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, flowlayout

I have a strange issue with dialog which contains an inner view - FlowLayout.

After I add some items to my FlowLayout, padding between ed f the dialog and keys become bigger. Even if I recreate dialog, padding still there.

```
public WatchersDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

/**
 * Initialize drug picker dialog
 * Setup buttons and title and main view
 */
private void init() {
    if (Utils.getInternetConnectionType(getContext()) == Utils.NO_INTERNET) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        setCustomTitle(inflater.inflate(R.layout.wathcer_dialog_title, null));
    } else {
        setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.watcher));
    }
    setView(getView(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPositiveButton(R.string.save, (dialogInterface, i) -> {

    });
    setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
}

private LinearLayout getView() {
    LinearLayout view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.wathcer_dialog_layout, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    watcherFlowLayout.setListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="+++"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <com.it4medicine.nm.ui.view.WatcherListLayout
            android:id="@+id/watcher_flow_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: ScrollView with android:layout_height="wrap_content" ??? inside View wich has android:layout_height="wrap_content", too? it doesn't make sens ... both those views should have match_parent also you can use fillViewport on ScrollView

Comment: anyway I would: 1. replace LinearLayout  with RelativeLayout (match_parent on both width and height) 2. AppCompatTextView width=0dp height=match_parent, aligntparent: left, top, right, 3. ScrollView with=match_parent, height=0dp, alignParent: bottom, bellow:id_of_AppCompatTextView ... now depends on what in the hell WatcherListLayout is should works or not

Comment: @Selvin, okay, but now dialog has too much blank space where it need to be scroleed(

Comment: even if you add few elements to WatcherListLayout ? problem is that ScrollView has to have some "well knowed" height (either fill parent or some static value)

Comment: @Selvin, fixed snx to you, but ScrollView I made wrap_content.

Comment: as i wrote ScrollView  with wrap_content doesn't make sens ... try to add multiple items into WatcherListLayout, so much that ScrollView should scroll and you will see ... AFAIK it will not scroll, and hides the views which can't fit the Dialog ...

Comment: @Selvin, all works with wrap_content)